# Spring @Query can't pass parameter in to sql native query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM register_log limit 50 offset :page",
            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM register_log ",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<RegisterLog> findRegisterLogsOptimized(@Param("page") int page);
```

Here page can't be seen by Java.

always have - `Hibernate: SELECT * FROM register_log limit 50 offset ?.`

here invocation
// in service

```
 public List<RegisterLog> findRegisterLogsOptimized(int page) {

        return registerLogRepository.findRegisterLogsOptimized(page);
    }
```

// in repository

```
registerLogService.findRegisterLogsOptimized(50);
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a stacktrace? In the screenshot it looks as if it is working and the parameter is simply not debug logged.

Comment: What you see in the log is the prepared statement. There concrete parameters are omitted and only the placeholder "?" is added instead. Try writing a testcase for the method and see if the correct response comes back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are saying this doesn't work, because it produces some exception.

Many (most? all?) database don't accept `offset` and `limit` as bound parameters.
If that is the case you need to remove the `offset` and `limit` clauses and instead pass a [`Pageable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) as an argument.
Spring Data JPA will then create the proper `offset` and `limit` clauses for you.